# .getAverage needs a class to the left of it

Tags: c++

I keep getting an error saying that "`.getAverage` needs a class to the left of it".

This is the assignment prompt:

> **Test Scores.** Write a class called `TestScores`. The class constructor should accept an array of test scores as its argument. The class should have a member function that returns the average of the test scores. If any test score in the array is negative or greater than 100, the class should throw an exception.
>
> There should be two classes for the exceptions; one should be called `NegativeScore` and other should be `TooLargeScore`. These exception classes will have a data member that is an integer value called score. This data member will be set in the constructor via the parameter. It should also provide a member function called `getScore` which returns score data member.
>
> The function in `TestScores` called `getAverages` will calculate the average (as a double) of the test scores in the array. It will also check if the score is negative or greater than 100. If it is negative it should throw an exception using the `NegativeScore` class. If the score is greater than 100 it should throw an exception using the `TooLargeScore` class.
>
> Main will create the instance of the `TestScores` class and catch the exceptions. So it needs to handle both exceptions and display the error message with the score that is invalid.

```
#pragma once
/*
Specification file: TestScores.h
Program: P3W3A1
Author: Joseph Bales
Created: 9/15/16
Revised: 9/15/16
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "NegativeScore.h"
#include "TooLargeScore.h"
using namespace std;

#ifndef TESTSCORES_H
#define TESTSCORES_H

const int SIZE = 5;
class TestScores
{
private:
    int testScore[];
public:
    //Exception Class 
    class NegativeScore
    {};

    //Exception Class
    class TooLargeScore
    {};

    //Default Constructor
    TestScores();

    //Constructor
    TestScores(int [], int SIZE);

    //Accessor/getter functions
    //getAverage accessor function
    double getAverage(int []);

};
#endif
[/code]
[code]

/*
Class Implementation Page: TestScores.cpp
Program: P3W3A1
Author: Joseph Bales
Created: 9/15/16
Revised: 9/15/16
*/
#include "TestScores.h"

//*******************************************
//Default Constructor that initializes the  *
//array of scores with zero's.              *
//*******************************************
TestScores::TestScores()
{
    testScore[0] = 0;
    testScore[1] = 0;
    testScore[2] = 0;
    testScore[3] = 0;
    testScore[4] = 0;
    testScore[5] = 0;
}

//********************************************
//The TestScores Constructor accepts an      *
//array of test scores as its argument.      *
//********************************************
TestScores::TestScores(int scoreArr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        testScore[i] = scoreArr[i];
}

//********************************************
//The getAverage function returns the average*
//of all the test scores, and throws an      *
//exception if one is negative or above 100. *
//********************************************
double TestScores::getAverage(int score[])
{
    double total = 0;
    double number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)//***
    {
        if (score[i] < 0)
        {
            throw NegativeScore();
        }
        else if (score[i] > 100)
        {
            throw TooLargeScore();
        }
        else
        {
            number = score[i];
        }
        total += number;

    }
    return total / SIZE;//***
}
[/code]
[code]
#pragma once
/*
Specification file: NegativeScore.h
Program: P3W3A1
Author: Joseph Bales
Created: 9/15/16
Revised: 9/15/16
*/

#ifndef NEGATIVESCORE_H
#define NEGATIVESCORE_H

//Exception Class 
class NegativeScore
{
private:
    int score;
public:
    NegativeScore(int);
    int getScore();
};
#endif
[/code]
[code]

/*
Class Implementation Page: NegativeScore.cpp
Program: P3W3A1
Author: Joseph Bales
Created: 9/15/16
Revised: 9/15/16
*/
#include "NegativeScore.h"

NegativeScore::NegativeScore(int s)
{
    score = s;
}

int NegativeScore::getScore()
{
    return score;
}
[/code]

[code]
#pragma once
/*
Specification file: TooLargeScore.h
Program: P3W3A1
Author: Joseph Bales
Created: 9/15/16
Revised: 9/15/16
*/

#ifndef TOOLARGESCORE_H
#define TOOLARGESCORE_H

//Exception Class
class TooLargeScore
{
private:
    int score;
public:
    TooLargeScore(int);
    int getScore() const;

};
#endif
[/code]
[code]
/*
Class Implementation Page: TooLargeScore.cpp
Program: P3W3A1
Author: Joseph Bales
Created: 9/15/16
Revised: 9/15/16
*/

#include "TooLargeScore.h"

TooLargeScore::TooLargeScore(int s)
{
    score = s;
}

int TooLargeScore::getScore() const
{
    return score;
}

[/code]

[code]
/*
Main Program Page: Source.cpp
Program: P3W3A1
Author: Joseph Bales
Created: 9/15/16
Revised: 9/15/16
*/
#include "TestScores.h"


int main()
{
    //Array to hold scores
    int score[5];

    //get test scores from user
    cout << "Please Enter " << SIZE << " test scores: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cin >> score[i];
    }

    //Check for exceptions
    try
    {
        ///HERE IS THE ERROR.
        TestScores object(int score[], int SIZE);
        cout << "The average of the scores is " << object.getAverage() << endl;
    }
    catch (TestScores::TooLargeScore)
    {
        cout << "Error: The value entered was too high.\n";
    }
    catch (TestScores::NegativeScore)
    {
        cout << "Error: A Negative value was entered.\n";
    }
    cout << "End of the program.\n";

    return 0;
}
[/code]
```

Comment: Hint; you are basically posting **a lot** of requirements and code. It would be better to turn to the help center first, to learn how to ask questions here. For example, read about creating a **minimal** viable example.

Comment: `TestScores object(int score[], int SIZE);` declares a function.  (If you don't know why this declares a function then revisit what function declarations are). Maybe you meant to declare an object, e.g. `TestScores object{score, SIZE};`

Comment: This has nothing to do with exceptions - you just happened to put this bogus code inside a try block, it would be the same error anywhere else too

Answer (score 2):

```
///HERE IS THE ERROR.
TestScores object(int score[], int SIZE);
cout << "The average of the scores is " << object.getAverage() << endl;
```

You have not declared a new object called `object` of type `TestScores`.  Instead, you have forward-declared a function prototype called `object` that returns a value of type `TestScores`.

Take out the type definitions and use your actual identifiers:

```
TestScores object( score, SIZE );
cout << "The average of the scores is " << object.getAverage( score ) << endl;
```

Edit: I noticed you have undefined behaviour in your constructors.  This is out of scope of your original question though.  But you might want to consider giving `testScores` a size.

Comment: Also `getAverage` needs an int array/pointer argument.

Comment: Oh right.  Good spotting.  I think the volume of code in the question that boiled down to one line just made my eyes give up.

Answer (score 0):

in main 
you are declaring function prototype by specifying int in the parameter list,
TestScores object(int score[], int SIZE);

change it to :
TestScores object(score,SIZE);